# How can I tell other threads in threadpool to stop after one thread completes the task?

Tags: java, multithreading, concurrency, java.util.concurrent

**Here is my code:**

```
class Processor implements Runnable {

    private int id;
    private Integer interaction;
    private Set<Integer> subset;
    Iterator<Integer> iterator;
    ArrayList<Integer> par;

    public Processor(int id, Integer interaction, Set<Integer> subset, Iterator<Integer> iterator, ArrayList<Integer> par) {
        this.id = id;
        this.interaction = interaction;
        this.subset = subset;
        this.par = par;
        this.iterator = iterator;
    }

    public void run() {
        System.out.println("Starting: " + this.id);
        if (this.par.contains(this.interaction)) {
            this.subset.add(this.interaction);
            increaseScore(this.subset);
            if (!this.subset.contains(this.interaction)) {
                //TELL ALL OTHER THREADS TO STOP WHILE THIS THREAD REMOVES THE VALUE FROM THE ITERATOR
                iterator.remove();
            }
        }

        System.out.println("Completed: " + this.id);

    }
}

public class ConcurrentApp {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        ExecutorService executor = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(4);
        ArrayList<Integer> par1 = new ArrayList < Integer > ();
        long start = System.nanoTime();

        int i = 1;
        while ((par1.size() > i)) {
            for (Iterator<Integer> iterator = par1.iterator(); iterator.hasNext();) {
                Integer interaction = iterator.next();
                ArrayList<Integer> removed = new ArrayList<Integer> (par1);
                removed.remove(interaction);
                ArrayList<Set<Integer>> subsets = getSubsets(removed, i);
                for (int j = 0; j < subsets.size(); j++) {
                    executor.submit(new Processor(j, interaction, subsets.get(j), iterator, par1));
                }
                executor.shutdown();
                System.out.println("All tasks submitted");
                try {
                    executor.awaitTermination(1, TimeUnit.DAYS);
                } catch(InterruptedException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
            System.out.println("All tasks completed");
            i++;
        }
        long end = System.nanoTime();

        System.out.println("Program Completed in: " + (end - start) * 0.000000001);

    }
}
```

**My code flow is as follows:**

1. Start with an ArrayList of Integers called par and iterate through each element (we'll call A) in this collection
2. Remove A from par to obtain B
3. Find all subsets of size i (in the range 1 to par.size())
4. [*Multithreaded*] For each subset of size i, add back in A to obtain a new collection C. Then find the value that when deleted increases the score of C the most. [*Condition*]If that value is A, delete A from par and move on to the next element in par. If A is not deleted for any of the subsets of size i, continue to the next element in par.

My intention is for each thread to work with one of the subsets and perform the *Multithreaded* step above until one of the threads meets the *Condition*. I think I implemented this correctly but would appreciate a second set of eyes since I'm new to concurrent programming.

**Question 1:** In the multithreaded step above, how can I tell all the other working threads from the threadpool to stop their task and go back into the threadpool once a single thread meets the *Condition*?

**Questions 2:** Is there a way for me to have multiple threads simultaneously work on different sets of different sized subsets (so multiple values of i at once) AND have multiple threads perform the *Multithreading* step above for a given set of subsets (which is what I've already done)? Essentially this is like breaking my entire job into two tasks: Task 1 is to look at the sets of subsets of size 1, 2, 3...par.size() and Task 2 is to look at each element in the set of subsets.

Appreciate the help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Q1: Use a volatile static variable (maybe a volatile AtomicLong) that all threads can check for completion, and update when they have completed the activity.

Q2: It's definitely possible. You'd have set up a Runnable that could take your Shapes and the range of subset size to work on. But from what I can see, this is probably overkill: Task 2 (the part that you've done) is going to need much more processing power than Task 1, so you might as well just keep it the way you're doing it now

Please tell me if I've misread your question

Comment: For Q1's response, do you mean I could have something like a boolean volatile variable set to False and then have a while loop that continuously checks this variable within the "run" method of Processor. Then when the condition is met by a thread, I can just set the variable to True?

Comment: @Chandra_Rathnam yes that's the idea

Comment: Makes sense! However, wouldn't threads working on Task 2 when the _Condition_ is met still perform whatever computation they were doing (i.e. the score computation, which can be very time consuming) until they reach the end of the loop? Or does a while loop check that it's condition is met at every line of code (sorry for this basic question) so if I change the value of the static volatile variable, it'll immediately exit the while loop for that thread?

Comment: It won't check on every line of code, but that's a good thing. By just checking once in the while loop... or even once every 50 or 100 iterations in the while loop (depending on how intensive each iteration is) you will actually achieve higher performance - it's a balance between how often to check and how much that check is delaying the regular processing

Comment: Ahh makes sense. Thank you so much for the explanations. I appreciate not just getting an answer but also understanding how all of this works :). Best response I've ever gotten!

Comment: I added the AtomicBoolean but now the program breaks after doing just one set of subsets (that is for just one value of i). Do you have any suggestions?

Comment: @Chandra_Rathnam it's hard to say without seeing your code. However If it's just running 1 value of of i, then there's something wrong with your multithreading. For each i, it should be spawning off multiple threads to do the work, right?

Comment: I realized that after every value of i, I had to reset the AtomicBoolean back to it's original value so that subsequent iterations of i wouldn't already think the task is complete. However, now, my problem is that I can't get the removal of an element from my original list PA without getting concurrent modification errors. Im trying to use a CopyOnWriteList but the final result doesn't have the deletions applied. I'd really appreciate any help. I can post my new code as another question but I'd really like your help since you've helped so much already.

Answer (score 0):

**Question 1:** In the multithreaded step above, how can I tell all the other working threads from the threadpool to stop their task and go back into the threadpool once a single thread meets the Condition?

Use [invokeAny](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ExecutorService.html#invokeAny-java.util.Collection-long-java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit-) API of `ExecutorService`

```
<T> T invokeAny(Collection<? extends Callable<T>> tasks,
                long timeout,
                TimeUnit unit)
         throws InterruptedException,
                ExecutionException,
                TimeoutException
```

> Executes the given tasks, returning the result of one that has completed successfully (i.e., without throwing an exception), if any do before the given timeout elapses. Upon normal or exceptional return, tasks that have not completed are cancelled. The results of this method are undefined if the given collection is modified while this operation is in progress.

**Questions 2:** Is there a way for me to have multiple threads simultaneously work on different sets of different sized subsets (so multiple values of i at once) AND have multiple threads perform the Multithreading step above for a given set of subsets (which is what I've already done)?

You can do it with . If you face any issues in implementing above, share your issues. Even if you want to wait for completion of all tasks, you can use [invokeAll](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ExecutorService.html#invokeAll-java.util.Collection-). If you want to improve the performance, you can use [ForkJoinPool](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ForkJoinPool.html)